# Drawing rectangle and square using same function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw

I want to draw both rectangle and square using same `var rectangle` in my program. I have modified the function to draw square, given `modeOptions = { "Rectangle", "Square" }` what needs to be added below to work for both, rectangle and square. Please suggest. Thanks

Can also see the question at : http://jsfiddle.net/farey/qP3kV/6/

```
var rectangle=(function() {
  var inDrag=false,downPos,upPos;
  var obj;
  // temporary length for square
  var temp;
  return {
    fillStyle: "none",
    strokeStyle: "blue",
    lineWidth: 5,
    construct: function(pos,parent) {
      obj=Object.create(parent);
      obj.minx=obj.maxx=pos.x;
      obj.miny=obj.maxy=pos.y;
      if (fillColor!="inherit")
        obj.fillStyle=fillColor;
      if (strokeColor!="inherit")
        obj.strokeStyle=strokeColor;
      if (strokeThickness!="inherit")
        obj.lineWidth=strokeThickness;
      },
    draw: function(selected) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle=this.fillStyle;
      ctx.strokeStyle=(selected) ?
                      "gray" : this.strokeStyle;
      ctx.lineWidth=this.lineWidth;
      // making 3rd & fourth argument same for square. greater of maxx and maxy should be there

        if (this.maxx - this.minx > this.maxy - this.miny)
        {  temp = this.maxx - this.minx 
        }
        else
            temp = this.maxy - this.miny

        ctx.rect(this.minx,this.miny,temp,temp);

     // else 
     // ctx.rect(this.minx,this.miny,this.maxx - this.minx,this.maxy - this.miny )

      ctx.fill();
      if (selected) {
        ctx.moveTo(this.minx,this.miny);
        ctx.lineTo(this.maxx,this.maxy);
        ctx.moveTo(this.minx,this.maxy);
        ctx.lineTo(this.maxx,this.miny);
        }
      ctx.stroke();
      },
    mousedown: function(event) {
      downPos=event;
      rectangle.construct(downPos,drawObject[containingBox4point(downPos)]);
      inDrag=true;
      },
    mousemove: function(event) {
      if (!inDrag)
      {
        drawPrevious();
        drawCursor(event,containingBox4point(event));
        return;
      }
      upPos=event;
      if (upPos.x>downPos.x) {
        obj.minx=downPos.x;
        obj.maxx=upPos.x;
        }
      else {
        obj.minx=upPos.x;
        obj.maxx=downPos.x;
        }
      if (upPos.y>downPos.y) {
        obj.miny=downPos.y;
        obj.maxy=upPos.y;
        }
      else {
        obj.miny=upPos.y;
        obj.maxy=downPos.y;
        }
      drawPrevious();
      obj.draw(containingBox(obj)==(-1));
      drawCursor(event,containingBox4point(upPos));
      },
    mouseup: function(event) {
      // commit rectangle
      rectangle.mousemove(event);
      if (!inDrag)
        return;
      if (containingBox(obj)==(-1))
        trace("U and ur box are evil . . .");
      else
      {
        drawObject.push(obj);
        trace("Rectangle props for new box "+String(drawObject.length-1)+
          ":  filled with "+ fillColor+
          "   stroked with "+strokeColor+
          "   @ thickness "+ strokeThickness);
      }
      inDrag=false;
      drawPrevious();
      },
    mouseout: function(event) {
      inDrag=false;
      drawPrevious();
      }
    };
  })(); // rectangle
```

Comment: try jsfiddle.net,simplify your question.post only the relevant path of your code in question.This would get you more responses.

Comment: Ok. I have posted it there as well. Thanks.

Comment: then post the link in your question...

Comment: here: (not sure if that was the right way to do.) http://jsfiddle.net/farey/qP3kV/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qP3kV/5/
...this is not working

Comment: its opening the post for me. :/

Comment: the code is not working!!!

Comment: I have posted almost all the code in that post. If you scroll down in the result section, you will see what the code is required to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To force the resulting rectangle to be only a square, you need to modify your rectangle mousemove method.

The modification would enforce that this is always true:

```
Math.abs(obj.maxx-obj.minx) ==  Math.abs(obj.maxy-obj.miny).
```

**It’s up to you to determine how your want to enforce that result.**

For example, assuming upPos is right and down from downPos:

You could let the horizontal length win:

```
obj.maxy = obj.miny+(obj.maxx-obj.minx);
```

You could let the vertical length win:

```
obj.maxx = obj.minx+(obj.maxy-obj.miny);
```

You could even let the minx/miny float to create a square:

```
obj.minx = obj.maxx – (obj.maxy-obj.miny);

//  or 

obj.miny= obj.maxy – (obj.maxx-obj.minx);
```

Comment: I want to draw both rectangle and square. I modified the code and was able to draw square. But how can I draw both. I have tried another radio Button, it doesn't work.